# Inheritance or composition for Category-Subcategory-Tags categorization

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, categories, categorization

I need to develop categorization, which needs to have these characteristics:

- An item may belong to **one or more** categories;
- The same item may (and usually will) also belong to **one or more subcategories**
- A subcategory is to have **one or more parent categories**
- A subcategory is to feature several around a dozen **tags**
- In an ideal world, **categories themselves** could have **tags assigned** to them

At this moment, I'm considering:

- Having a base class `Taxonomy` from which `Category`, `Subcategory` and `Tag` would inherit. **However, these would not have very specific attributes of their own to justify such a decision**
- Use **composition** instead, but I'm unsure if I understood it correctly (it may not be suitable for this case).

Maybe there are better ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

`Taxonomy` seems like a good candidate for a "has a" rule set. The first thing I would consider would be have a `Taxonomy` interface that each `Category` class would implement. A `Subcategory` class could also implement an interface, one that extends upon `Taxonomy`. Finally, `Tags` also could be an extension of a `Taxonomy` interface, as an area of study should have tags. The composition could take place with a `CategoryComp` class that implements the highest taxonomy interface and holds references to the common objects. Another alternative might be to explore beans/wiring in Java.